# How these fractions becomes this?

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-series

Today I was trying to solve an integral for a Fourier series. I looked at the solution and this was the solution:

\begin{align*}
 C_n
 &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} x^2 e^{-inx} \,\text{d}x \\
 \xrightarrow{\text{integration by parts}}
 C_n
 &= \frac{1}{2\pi}
 \left[
 - \frac{x^2 e^{-inx}}{in}
 - \frac{2 x e^{-inx}}{-n^2}
 - \frac{2 e^{-inx}}{-in^2}
 \right]^{2\pi}_0 \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \left[ \frac{4 i \pi^2}{n} + \frac{4 \pi}{n^2} \right]
\end{align*}

I know how they solved it but cannot get how this part $$
 C_n
 = \frac{1}{2\pi}
 \left[
 - \frac{x^2 e^{-inx}}{in}
 - \frac{2 x e^{-inx}}{-n^2}
 - \frac{2 e^{-inx}}{-in^2}
 \right]^{2\pi}_0
$$
becomes this:
$$
 \frac{1}{2\pi} \left[ \frac{4 i \pi^2}{n} + \frac{4 \pi}{n^2} \right].
$$
Would you please clear it to me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Parfaitement illisible pour un non-arabophone.

Comment: In first photo which is that language??

Comment: @ArchisWelankar It's Persian and says 'Integration by parts'

Comment: @Nizar Yup, it's Persian.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Look at the edit, please.

Comment: I replaced the images by the actual text to make it more readable for the average user. Please correct it if I have made any mistakes.

Comment: What part don't you understand ? ("I know how they solved it but cannot get how" is not really helpful.)

Comment: @JendrikStelzner Thank you.

Comment: ...Especially since all this boils down to the notation $$\left[f(x)\right]_a^b=f(b)-f(a).$$

Comment: @YvesDaoust Doh! I cannot get everything after 'integration by part'

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's not sooo tough, is it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will leave away the factor $\frac{1}{2\pi}$. Plug in to obtain
$$\left.\left(-\frac{x^2 e^{-inx}}{in} - \frac{2x e^{-inx}}{-n^2}-\frac{2e^{-inx}}{-in^2}\right)\right|_{x=0}^{2 \pi} = \left(-\frac{(2 \pi)^2 e^{-2in \pi}}{in} - \frac{2(2\pi) e^{-2in\pi}}{-n^2}-\frac{2e^{-2in\pi}}{-in^2}\right)-\left(-\frac{2}{-in^2}\right).$$

Recall that $e^{2 i \pi n} = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and in this context clearly $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, the expression becomes

$$-\frac{4 \pi^2}{in}-\frac{4 \pi}{-n^2}-\frac{2}{-in^2}+\frac{2}{-in^2}.$$

Multiply the two fractions which still have an $i$ in the denominator by $\frac{i}{i}$ to get
$$-\frac{4 i\pi^2}{-n} - \frac{4 \pi}{-n^2}-\frac{2i}{n^2} + \frac{2i}{n^2}$$
which of course you can simplify to end up with the desired
$$\frac{4i \pi^2 }{n}+\frac{4 \pi}{n^2}.$$